# AdSense Management API for Reporting through R

Tags: r, api, rest, adsense, adsense-api

I have been searching the internet for ways to access the AdSense API via R and have not been able to find documentation. It uses REST with OAuth 2.0.

I am looking to use the API for reporting.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

There's a client library to access the Prediction API with R. Prediction and the AdSense Management API are both REST and use Oauth2 so it should be easy to modify the code at:

https://code.google.com/p/google-prediction-api-r-client/